# Changing Password in Exchange Server only

Tags: exchange, password, users

I created 1 user in AD and created mail box in exchange 2010 server. We implemented password policy for changing password in 45 days.

I was having crunch on licenses so, I deleted AD user and did not delete his mail box, so that he can access his mailbox.

Now, The questions are :
How can I change his password?
How can I prevent his password from expiring?

Remember that I have deleted his AD user.

Comment: You can't. Without an AD user account you have nothing to authenticate to. You won't be able to access that mailbox

Comment: Also in most cases deleting the AD user and leaving the exchange mailbox won't help any licensing problem. In most situations a user accessing an exchange mailbox needs both a windows CAL and an exchange CAL.

Answer (score 1):

That is impossible. Microsoft Exchange simply does not work without Active Directory. If you deleted user in Active Directory, mailbox becames disconnected - without any user to authenticate against.

Answer (score 0):

> I was having crunch on licenses

The correct answer to this question is to either acquire more licenses or switch to a platform that you can afford.